# VSTO: How to forbid the context menu of chart in presentation slide?

Tags: vsto, powerpoint, powerpoint-2007

I'm developing an add-in of PowerPoint in VSTO.

When I have inserted a chart into the slide,
and I don't want show the context menu when user right-click the chart.

I forbid some command button of powerpoint,

```
<command idMso="TabChartToolsDesign" getEnabled="GetVisible"/>
<command idMso="ChartChangeType" getEnabled="GetVisible"/>
<command idMso="ChartResetToMatchStyle" getEnabled="GetVisible"/>
<command idMso="ChartPlotAreaOptionsDialog" getEnabled="GetVisible"/>
```

but it's not enough. some command buttons are still enable.

what can i do for this ?

Answer (score 0):

You're sure your GetVisible callback(s) are returning false? If so, you're probably missing a control. You download the full list of controls/names here:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=4329D9E9-4D11-46A5-898D-23E4F331E9AE&displaylang=en